# Revit API: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found on Autodesk.Revit.UI.IExternalApplication

Tags: f#, revit-api, revitpythonshell, pyrevit

I am working on an F# scripting editor similar to RevitPythonShell or pyRevit.
Since it is a non modal WPF window I try to follow the [`ExternalEvent`](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2014/ENU/Revit/files/GUID-0A0D656E-5C44-49E8-A891-6C29F88E35C0-htm.html) pattern to evaluate scripts.
On the main addin class that has the `IExternalApplication` interface I also create some utility members to raise the external event. I created a static member to access the current instance of this addin class.
see addin: https://github.com/goswinr/Seff.Revit/blob/minimal/Addin.fs#L51

Once the addin is running I send a reference (`#r @"D:\Git\Seff.Revit\bin\Debug\net472\Seff.Revit.dll"`) of the currently running addin to Fsharp Interactive.
The static members are visible with the correct signatures but uppon using them I get a `System.MissingMethodException`. 
This happens only to members that use the Revit namespace. Members unrelated to Revit work as expected.

[image]
[image]
Other members work fine:
[image]

**Edit:**
I only have this bug when I start Revit with a project to open.
When first starting Revit and then opening a project from within revit this error does not happen.

[This Revit and F# repro](https://github.com/JordanMarr/revit-fabulous) notes a similar bug at the end of the readme.

Comment: Maybe Fhsarp core related? Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33105382/why-do-i-get-a-missing-method-exception-runtime-when-creating-a-sqlclient-type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compiled it in `net462` instead of `net472`, that solved it